# How to make Amazon Echo device to control devices in the same room with the same name?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I have two Amazon Echo devices installed in two rooms. I have created groups and added devices of the rooms to their respective groups. But I have some devices with the same name. For example, I have two devices named Light, one in the bedroom and another in the office room. When I try to turn on/off the light of the bedroom by speaking into the Echo device of the bedroom, it turns on/off the light of the office room. When I speak to the Echo device of the office room, it turns on/off the light of the office room, which matches with the normal behaviour.

How can I make Amazon Echo devices to control the devices in the same group, in case of duplicate names among all my devices?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you basically can't. However, if you name the lights "Office Light" & "Bedroom Light" and then ask Alexa to "turn on the lights" in each room, it will turn on all the lights in the group your echo is in. If you only have 1 light per group, you will be able to tell Alexa, "Turn on the lights" in either room even if the lights have unique names.